# Setter method is not being called in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, methods, overriding, setter

When I override the getters and setters for my class, and set the `miles` property elsewhere, the setter method is not called. What am I doing wrong?

I call the `miles` property here

```
// "entry" is an object that has a property of type CYDistance

if ([unitLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Miles"]) {
    entry.distance.miles = s.floatValue;
}
else if ([unitLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Kilometers"]) {
    entry.distance.kilometers = s.floatValue;
}
NSLog(@"Miles: %.2f", entry.distance.miles);
NSLog(@"Kilometers: %.2f", entry.distance.kilometers);
```

Distance.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CYDistance : NSObject {
    float miles, kilometers;
}

@property float miles;
@property float kilometers;

@end
```

Distance.m

```
#import "Distance.h"

@implementation CYDistance

- (float)miles {
    return miles;
}

- (float)kilometers {
    return kilometers;
}

- (void)setMiles:(float)m {
    miles = m;
    kilometers = m * 1.609344;
    NSLog(@"Set miles");
}

- (void)setKilometers:(float)k {
    kilometers = k;
    miles = k / 1.609344;
    NSLog(@"Set kilometers");
}

@end
```

Comment: Your implementation is for the class Distance while your interface is for the class CYDistance. Define the getters and setters in CYDistance.

Comment: Show the code where you're creating an instance of CYDistance and setting it's `miles` property.

Comment: Remove the @dynamic keywords, they're not used in this case anyway, and it's just confusing. Please provide an example of how you're calling the setter, too.

Comment: You almost never want to use `@dynamic`. Its purpose is fairly specific and not very common.

Comment: Your getter/setter methods look correct. Add NSLog() statements to your if/else if statement to see if the conditions are even being met.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following code...

```
entry.distance.miles = s.floatValue;
```

...if the value of `entry.distance` is `nil`, then the `miles` accessor will not be invoked.

Answer (score -1):

Try writing implementation as the following:

```
#import "Distance.h"

@implementation CYDistance

@synthesize miles = _miles;
@synthesize kilometers = _kilometers;

- (void)setMiles:(float)m {
    _miles = m;
    _kilometers = m * 1.609344;
    NSLog(@"Set miles");
}

- (void)setKilometers:(float)k {
    _kilometers = k;
    _miles = k / 1.609344;
    NSLog(@"Set kilometers");
}

@end
```

This way there is no mistake when referring the ivars.